# Call to undefined method Spatie\Analytics\AnalyticsFacade::fetchVisitorsAndPageViews()

Tags: php, laravel, google-analytics

I'm trying to implement this code from the package spatie/laravel-analytics

```
use Analytics;
use Spatie\Analytics\AnalyticsClientFactory;
use Spatie\Analytics\Period;

 // These keys are the same as the config file
$analyticsConfig = [
    'view_id' => env('ANALYTICS_VIEW_ID'),
    'service_account_credentials_json' => storage_path('app/analytics/service-account-credentials.json'),
    'cache_lifetime_in_minutes' => 60 * 24,
    'cache' => [
        'store' => 'file',
    ],
];

$client = AnalyticsClientFactory::createForConfig($analyticsConfig);

$analytics = new Analytics($client, $analyticsConfig['view_id']);

// Use $analytics to get analytics
```

But I got stuck in an error saying

```
Call to undefined method Spatie\Analytics\AnalyticsFacade::fetchVisitorsAndPageViews()
```

It seems like I'm using the AnalyticsFacade instead of Analytics when I'm doing

```
$analytics->fetchVisitorsAndPageViews(Period::days(7));
```

after the code above. Am I doing this wrong? How can I use the Analytics instead of AnalyticsFacade?

Comment: Check out which class is being imported for the "Analytics" class up top of the script. Might just be trying to access the wrong class.

Comment: Why not use the official php client library why are you using a third party one?  https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/web-php

Comment: @Jeto the error happened at when I tried to use the analytics in this ```$analytics->fetchVisitorsAndPageViews(Period::days(7));```

Comment: @goaty Your `use Analytics;` at the top of your script denotes that you're not using the class from the Spatie namespace, but some kind of Facade that resides in the same namespace as your script. Should be `use Spatie\Analytics\Analytics;` if you want to use the class from the package.

Comment: @Jeto oh great that works. I forgot I can do that too I thought I added a different class.